# How to set null safety to parent variable so we do not need to loop for the children vars

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have problem with putting null safety into child vars since there are many. I just want to set it to the parent. I already did it but is there any shortcut where we can just put into parent variable then we do not need to loop for the children vars

```
return ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  final DataAd object = snapshot.data![index]; => Here is the parent
                  final images = object.images!['images']; => I dont want to repeat here
                  if(object!=null) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(object.title!), => this one
                          Image(image: NetworkImage('${globals.domain}${object.dir}/${images![0]}')), => and this one for example
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  else{
                    return CallLoading();
                  }
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context,index) => Divider(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            );
```

I am new into flutter, I really appreciate any given answer. Thank you.

Comment: Using `!` have risk of getting null from `snapshot.data![index]`. I will encourage you to check null 1st then proceed to the next part.  If you like to make it nullable, use `final DataAd? object = snapshot.data?[index];`  You can check more about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: whether children are null is not related to whether the parent is null. It could very well be that `snapshot.data![index]` is not null but `object.images` is. Not only is what you want not possible, it also doesn't make any sense. If you want to avoid having to use `!` you could just make sure they are never `null` and make those fields not nullable

Comment: It also seems strange to me also that `object.images` seems to be a map with key `"images"`. does this map have any other keys? if not why is it a map at all and isn't it directly an array with images? Maybe you could share you `DataAd` class. I think improving that one might solve your issue

Comment: @IvoBeckers the images is an object map because it contain array of main image, brochure image, and 360image. Anyway, the data will surely never null from backend but just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a guard to your function and Dart compiler will see that value can't be `null`.

Example:

```dart
void foo(String? data) {
  String _data; 
  if (data == null) return; // The guard.
  _data = data; // Will not ask for null check because it cannot be null.
  print(_data);
}

// Without guard:
void foo(String? data) {
  String _data; 
  //if (data == null) return; 
  _data = data; // Error: A value of type ‘String?’ can’t be assigned to a variable of type ‘String’.
  print(_data);
}

// With default value.
void foo(String? data) {
  String _data = data ?? 'Empty'; // <- Convert to non nullable.
  // Do what you want with _data
  print(_data);
}
```